# Upper bound of a totally ordered set

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let $E$ be a vector space and $\mathcal{C}$ the collection of all linearly independent subsets of $E$. If $\mathcal{A}$ is a totally ordered subset (chain) of $\mathcal{C}$, define $$S = \bigcup_{S_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{A}} S_{\alpha}.$$ Prove that $S \in \mathcal{C}$.

I can see this result in my head, but I'm struggling with a formal proof. I've to show that $S$ is a l.i. set on $E$ (of course, $S$ is an upper bound of $\mathcal{A}$). If $S$ has infinite cardinal, I've to prove that every finite subset of $S$ (say $S_n$) is l.i. on $E$. Let's take any finite subset of $S$: $\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\} \subset E$. Now suppose that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i x_i = 0.$$
By the definition of $S$, the $x_i$'s must lie in $S_{\alpha}$, for some finite $\alpha$'s. Since $S_{\alpha}$ is l.i. on $E$, any finite subset is l.i., so I can split the above sum like
$$\underbrace{c_1x_1+\cdots+c_jx_j}_{\in S_{\alpha_1}} + \cdots$$ with $x_1,\dots,x_j \in S_{\alpha_1}$, etc. All $c_1=\dots=c_j=0$ because every $S_{\alpha}$ is l.i. But here, I'm not using the fact that $\mathcal{A}$ is a chain. Am I overcomplicating things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take any finite subset of $S$: $\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\} \subset S$.
By the definition of $S$, the $x_i \in S_{\alpha_i} $  for $i=1,2,..n$. Since $\mathcal{A}$ is a chain there is $\alpha_T \in \{\alpha_1 , ...,\alpha_n\}$ such that $S_{\alpha_i} \subset S_{\alpha_T} $  for $i=1,2,..n.$ therefore all $x_i \in S_{\alpha_T}$ thus the set $\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}$ is linearly independent as a subset of linearly independent set $S_{\alpha_T}$

Comment: Thanks! I was indeed overthinking